# How to pick multiple array elements in swift 4.2?

Tags: arrays, swift

Currently making a little quiz app and I store questions in an array.

This is the method that I`m trying out, but it only shows a single question.

```
var questionList = ["Question1","Question2","Question3","Question4","Question5"]
print(questionList.randomElement()!)
```

How to pick several random elements from there?

Let`s say I have 100 questions, and I only want to show a group of random 10 questions??

Answer (score 5):

[Shuffle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994757-shuffled) the array and get the first 10 elements using [prefix(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689487-prefix)

> If the maximum length exceeds the number of elements in the
>   collection, the result contains all the elements in the collection.

```
let arr = Array(1..<100)
let shuffledArr = arr.shuffled()
print(shuffledArr.prefix(10))//[35, 61, 9, 80, 68, 37, 22, 79, 57, 32]
```

Make sure the array length is greater than the subarray count

```
let questionList = ["Question1","Question2","Question3","Question4","Question5"] 
print(questionList.shuffled().prefix(2))//["Question5", "Question2"]
```